# Prove $(SFG)$ is tangent to $(ABC)$

Tags: geometry, contest-math

[image]

Let the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$ intersect the circle with diameter $AI$ at $S$ where $I$ is the incentre of triangle $ABC$.
Let $M$ be the midpoint of major arc $BAC$. Let the circle $BIC$ intersect circumcircle $SIM$ at $X$. Let $MX$ and $MI$ meet $BC$ at $G$ and $F$ respectively. Prove that circle $SFG$ is tangent to circle $ABC$.
The way I had in mind was to use power of a point wirh a point circle at $S$,  sadly I couldn't find the solution.  Please help..

Comment: Can you post a figure?

Comment: Sir now I have corrected the question..

Comment: Doesn't look to be true to me? Could you post a diagram?

Comment: I agree, a diagram would help a lot with this problem.

Comment: @jlammy I added a diagram.  Feel free to replace with a better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using some advanced tools of projective geometry. I apologise if this is not at all helpful -- perhaps tomorrow I'll see if there's an easier solution...

Let $N$ be the midpoint of minor arc $BC$. Let the incircle touch sides $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ at $P$, $Q$, $R$.

First, an inversion centre $N$ radius $NB=NI=NC$ shows that $N$, $P$ and $S$ are collinear. By the radical axis theorem, $MS$, $IX$ and $BC$ concur at $K$. Then
$$-1=S(B,C;M,N)=(B,C;K,P),$$
which implies that $QR$ goes through $K$ too.

Consider cyclic quadrilateral $BICX$. By Brokard's theorem, the polar of $K$ in circle $(BIC)$ passes through $Y=BX\cap CI$ and $Z=BI\cap CX$. But the polar of $M$ in circle $(BIC)$ is the line $BC$, so by La Hire's theorem the polar of $K$ goes through $M$ too. Now $(B,C;P,K)=-1$ implies that the polar of $K$ passes through $P$ as well. So $M,P,Y,Z$ are collinear.

Now by the dual of Desargues' involution theorem on $BICX$ and point $M$, we have that $(MB,MC)$, $(MI,MX)$, $(MY,MZ)$ are pairs of an involution. This induces the involution $(B,C)$, $(G,F)$, $(P,P)$ on line $BC$. But the unique involution that swaps $B$, $C$ and fixes $P$ is harmonic conjugation in the points $K$, $P$. Hence $(K,P;F,G)=-1$.

Together with $\angle KSP=90^{\circ}$, this implies that $SP$ is the angle bisector of $\angle FSG$. Since $SP$ goes through $N$, a homothety at $S$ implies the desired result.

Comment: Sir, this is very helpful... I am a lazy typer thats why I didn't write what I did completely. Indeed I had used harmonics and SD lemma but I don't know DDIT thats why I couldb't find a complete solution... Thak you very much

Comment: @Ken what’s “SD lemma?”

Comment: Sharky devil lemma- please use above notations,  it states N P S are collinear

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c946900